# Convergence of functions of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

I know that

> IF $X_n$ is a sequence of random variables that converges to $X$ *almost surely*, then for any continuous function $g:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}\ ,\ g(X_n) $ converges to $g(X)$ *almost surely*.

Now if I replace *almost surely* with *in probability*, the statement still holds.

My question:

Does the statement hold for convergence *in law*?

Comment: Yes; this is known as the continuous mapping or Mann-Wald theorem.

Comment: Perfect answer!

Comment: Could you write the definition of convergence in law your have at your disposal? The proof may be simpler or not according to the definition you have.

Comment: A sequence $X_1,X_2,.....$ of real-valued random variable is said to converge in distribution, or converge weakly, or converge in law to a random variable $X$ if $\lim_{n\to \infty} F_n(x)=F(x)$

for every number $x\in\Bbb{ R }$ at which F is continuous.

Answer (score 2):

Yes $X_n$ converges to $X$ in law iff $E(h(X_n))$ converges to $E(h(X)) \forall h$ bounded and continuous from $\Bbb{R}$ to $\Bbb{R}$. Apply this on $g(X_n)$ and $g(X)$.

Comment: Aar ektu explain korle bhalo hoto.

Comment: Aar PR ki convergence in law'r ei definition ta bolechilo?

Comment: Ha bolechilo... Btw tui ke 

Comment: Ekhane bolbo na. Kalke bole debo.